# How can I make one column per foreach using bootstap?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

For a web dev projet for my school, I've to program a Trello-like. I've to display board, with different columns but I really don't know how to generate one column per element in my foreach loop.
If someone could help me I'd be thanksfull!

Here's the foreach loop:

```
                <?php foreach ($currentColumns as $currentColumn): ?>
                    
                    (<?= $currentColumn['title']?> ) <?= $currentColumn['position'] ?>
                
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here, you can do like this..

```
 <table>
        <tr>
           <?php foreach ($currentColumns as $currentColumn): ?>
                
              <td>
                 (<?= $currentColumn['title']?> ) <?= $currentColumn['position'] ?>
              </td>
            
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And do you know how could I manage spaces between <td>? I've tried:         <table class ="table border-spacing: 30px"> 
            <thead>
                 <tr> 
                        <?php foreach ($currentColumns as $currentColumn): ?>
                            <td>  
                                <strong>  <?= $currentColumn['title']?> </strong> 
                            </td> 
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>         
            </thead>         
        </table>

Comment: Apply one css class and give style it 
Padding:30px;
you got spces in them and also you can edit whtaever you want in thar class using diffrent style properties..